# Wrong Duplication on insertion using foreach function

Tags: php

i have this piece of code which permits me to insert on the database some information:

```
$att_id=$_REQUEST['att_id'];

$date=$_REQUEST['date'];
$pdv=$_REQUEST['checkbox'];

foreach($date as $val) {
foreach ($pdv as $pdv1) {
$values_arr[] = "('" . $val . "','" . $pdv1 . "','" . $att_id . "')";

$values = implode(", ", $values_arr);

$sql="INSERT INTO date_pdv (date,id_pdv,att_id) VALUES $values";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

Now, the points is that if array date has this values [1,2] and array pdv has this ones [1,2,3] what i should get in the database is:

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
2-1
2-2
2-3
```

But i don't... i get repeated values on the database... Should i be using any while length of the array..etc etc?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `echo $values;`?

Comment: Empty `$values_arr` at the beginning of each iteration and indent your code. In addition to that, please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Yes, it works, i mean, is not the problem with the values.. i need to insert something in order to loop them ... i mean depending from the length of the date value...

Comment: The insertion works fine, is just that the time a function gets inserted doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$att_id=$_REQUEST['att_id'];
$date=$_REQUEST['date'];
$pdv=$_REQUEST['checkbox'];

foreach($date as $val) {
  foreach ($pdv as $pdv1) {
    $values_arr[] = "('" . $val . "','" . $pdv1 . "','" . $att_id . "')";
  }
}
$values = implode(", ", $values_arr);
$sql="INSERT INTO date_pdv (date,id_pdv,att_id) VALUES $values";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

You were running the insert query on each iteration of the loop, which is why you were ending up with a lot of duplicated rows.

Note the placement of the closing `}` on the `foreach` loops

Comment: Hi :)
Thank you so much... it seems to be really easy this one.. we never thought of this :)
thanks!